# E-Mail external user when file is place in folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

Anyone know if its possible to email an external user when a file is placed in a certain folder in a document library?

Comment: I know the "alert me" feature could work however its coming from a different domain inside our tenant and we want to customize the email a bit.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with Power Automate. You can build a flow and use the **Send an Email V2** action under **Office 365 Outlook**, which allows you to type the external email address directly and customize email body.

See a reference here: [Sending Email through flow TO a NON 365 account.](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Sending-Email-through-flow-TO-a-NON-365-account/td-p/306420)

Flow templates to begin with: https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/

Comment: this is perfect however, one more question do you know if there is a way to choose who the sender is. We have multiple domains in our tenant and we want it to come from a certain domain and or sender?

Comment: @DickyDal I’m afraid not. The emails will be sent by “Microsoft Flow” on user’s behalf. This is the default behavior in all tenants.